# Dynamic mongoose schema parsing with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a ExpressJS and MongoDB project that involves parsing dynamic mongoose schema. The way I set up the dynamic schema is and parse it :

Step-1

```
//Creating a mongoose schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
measurements : [
        mongoose.Schema({
        time: String
    })
]});
```

Step-2

```
//Creating a mongoose model for the schema
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var user = new User();
user.measurements = [{time:req.body.time}]

//save the info
user.save(function(err) {
if (err)
 res.send(err);
 res.send({message: "User Info created"});
});
});
```

**Expected result**  :

A example with JSON validator to explain my goal clearly:

[image]
But the issue is my code posts data in the following way to the mongo database :

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to post new array object with time attribute instead of having the comma separated values. 
Any thoughts and suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way.

Try this:

```
var user = new User();
user.measurements.push({time:req.body.time});

//save the info
user.save(function(err) {
if (err)
 res.send(err);
 res.send({message: "User Info created"});
});
});
```